# The derivative of the logistic function

Tags: derivatives, logistic-regression

The logistic function is $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$, and its derivative is $f(x)*(1-f(x))$. [In the following page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Derivative), it shows the following equation:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} = \frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$$

which means $$f'(x) = e^x (1+e^x) - e^x \frac{e^x}{(1+e^x)^2} = \frac{e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}$$

I understand it so far, which uses the quotient rule $$\left(\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}\right)' = \frac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{h(x)^2}.$$

However, why is it then transformed into $f(x) * (1-f(x))$?

Answer (score 3):

Just start from the answer and work backwards.
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x)(1-f(x)) &= \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} \left( 1 - \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} \right)\\
&= \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} \left( \frac{1+e^x}{1+e^x} - \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} \right)\\
&= \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} \left( \frac{1}{1+e^x} \right) = \frac{e^x}{(1+e^x)^2} = f'(x)
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Yeah I can expand and confirm it. But I would like to know how it can be transformed into f(x) * (1-f(x))...

Comment: Then start from my last expression and work backwards.

Comment: There is no real secret here. This is not a general transformation you can use other places. It just happens to be true this time.

Comment: Hmmm... ok. But then I don't understand how the first person who reached the shortcut equation (`f(x) * (1-f(x))`) did reach it...

Comment: I wasn't there so I don't know, either! ;-) Sometimes it just takes a little luck and inspiration.

Comment: @Blaszard I'm a bit late to this, but there's a lotta advantage in calculating the derivative of a function and putting it in terms of the function itself. I'm sure many mathematicians noticed this over time, and they did it by asking "well lets put this in terms of f(x)". Viewing it like that reveals a lotta hidden clues about the dynamics of the logistic function. In fact, it's possible the chicken came first. Someone asked "when does y' = y(1-y)"? And from there they developed the logistic function.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $f'=f(1-f)$ is not so mysterious when you use **logarithmic differentiation**.

First, take the log of the second form of $f(x)$:
$$
\log f(x) =  x - \log(1+e^x)\tag1
$$
Now differentiate both sides of (1) with the help of the chain rule:
$$
\frac 1{f(x)}\cdot f'(x) = 1 - \frac1{1+e^x}\cdot e^x = 1 - f(x),\tag2
$$
and we're done!

In addition to being tidy, another benefit of the equation $f'=f(1-f)$ is that it's the fastest route to the second derivative of the logistic function:
$$
f''(x) = \frac d{dx}\left(f(x)-f(x)^2\right)=f'(x) - 2f(x)f'(x)=f'(x)\big(1-2f(x)\big)\tag3
$$